# Django Channels or StreamingHttpResponse for my needs?

Tags: django, http

I am currently working on a project web application using Django. I've prepared scripts (Python) beforehand which work fine but I've run into an issue trying to implement it with Django. I used html-requests sessions to keep the http connection alive during repeated requests. Should I be using Django Channels or StreamHttpResponse for the same effect or something different entirely?

Mainly, jQuery with AJAX to call view.function repeatedly until requirement met, but since fetching a url with session.get each time, it's creating a new session so I get the incorrect data back when trying to navigate a page. Searching anything session related with django will give me django sessions results.

I've managed to keep arbitrary data using django sessions or updating database, since I couldn't find a way to persist a custom class in between these calls, the only issue now is persisting the http connection.

Should I be looking into StreamHttpResponse, Django Channels, or something else entirely?

views.py

```
def search_for_product(request):
    current_user = request.user
    task_id = request.GET.get('task_id', None)
    current_task = GetWebsite(current_user, task_id)

    if current_task.configured_task.final_result:
        current_task.configured_task.search_again()
    elif current_task.configured_task.item_found:
        if current_task.configured_task.item_details_found:
                current_task.configured_task.finalize_result()
        else:
            current_task.configured_task.find_details()
    else:
        current_task.configured_task.find_item()

  data = {
    'status': current_task.configured_task.current_status
  }
  time.sleep(5)
  return JsonResponse(data)
```

Basically, search_for_product(result) will be called constantly until final results are saved. I return a status (boolean) for whether or not it succeeded in finding the item, got details of item, and ready to show results, which my AJAX function uses to repeat until final_result is True. This works fine except I need to keep the httpconnection open or the site will not show proper results and will fail on the second call searching for the item details.

```
function getStatus(statusLabel, rowID, taskID) {
    allTasks[rowID] = $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/page/search-for-product/',
        method: 'GET',
        data: {
            'task_id': taskID
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(data) {
        if (data.final) {
            console.log(data.status);
        } else {
            statusLabel.style.color = 'green';
            statusLabel.textContent = data.status;
            console.log(data.status);
            getStatus(statusLabel, rowID, taskID);
        }
    }).fail(function(data) {
        console.log(data.task_id);
        statusLabel.textContent = data.status;
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you post the view you're polling? What do you mean you're getting a new session each time? Does your app involve authentication?

Comment: Not necessarily need authentication, but I need to persist the http connection for what I'm trying to do. I have a view that is called repeatedly that performs certain tasks and returns some json which then updates the user on the current request status. Since the view function is called repeatedly, I can't just create a new HTMLSession each call, nor good practice to instantiate one globally (tried and doesn't work when pushed to heroku). I'll post some code when I'm near my laptop~

Comment: Please post the view -- it would be very helpful to understand how you're managing state so we can give you a suggestion.

Comment: Posted what I have in my views.py. Since my AJAX function is repeatedly calling search_for_product() until final_result is True, I don't think it's a good idea to create a HTMLSession in the view call, and I can't create it in my class either, since the class will just reinstantiate itself upon another call.

Comment: Your view uses `request.user` -- how are yoru AJAX calls being authenticated?

Comment: There isn't any authentication. The request.user is used to retrieve the user's task from the database specific to that user.

Comment: How is Django setting `request.user` for you then? There must be some authentication middleware setting this (perhaps sessions middleware?).

Comment: I've created a CustomUser which extends AbstractUser
```AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'```
And my settings.py

Comment: I think the issue is that you need to authenticate your AJAX calls (your view depends on `request.user`, which is set by Django's auth middleware). Can you include your JS?

Comment: JS included. Slightly modified.